# ArrayAdapter is changing the value of the CheckBox

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I don't know what's happening, I've a list of objects and depending of its state it's checked or not (`CheckBox`).
I've tried too many ways, because first of all I wanted to return an `ArrayList<myObject>` with the state updated, but I don't know why the objects were duplicating... and I ended up creating a `TreeSet` (don't know if it's the better way but at least the objects now doesn't repeat)... well the thing is that on my `Adapter` I have this :

```
final Sessio sessio = getItem(position);
    ALAdapter.add(sessio);
    vh.tvSessioName.setText(sessio.getName());
    vh.cbAssist.setChecked(sessio.isState());
    vh.cbAssist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "chaning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            sessio.setState(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

AlAdapter is `private TreeSet<Sessio> ALAdapter;`

this is working fine, the problem is at the time I re-open the dialog because I save the `TreeSet` on a `json` with `Gson` as follows :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = mPrefs.getString("ArrayListSesio", "");
Type type = new TypeToken <TreeSet<Sessio>> () {}.getType();
ArrayList<Sessio> obj = gson.fromJson(json,type);
return obj == null ? AlSessio : obj;
```

This is also working fine... I think the problem is on the `Adapter` because if I uncked some of the `CheckBox` and I change the state of the `Sessio` when I re-open the `Dialog` it shows the `Toast` like 15 times... and everytime I scroll up/down the state of the `CheckBox` changes....

What I'm doing wrong? Is there any other way to instead of save it to a `TreeSet` save it to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: Are you using listview?

Comment: @VishweshJainkuniya Yep

Comment: use recycler view as checkbox in list view randomly checks and uncheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is that views are reused, so before using `setChecked` method you should do this:

```
vh.cbAssist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
vh.cbAssist.setChecked(sessio.isState());
vh.cbAssist.setOnCheckedChangeListener(/* your listener here */);
```

Otherwise using `setChecked` will trigger listener.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: Yo @thetonrifles can you take a look on this ? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489404/trie-data-structure-implementing-addword)