# Trie data structure implementing addWord

Tags: java, tree, trie

I'm stuck with one project, I have to create a "word corrector" and I have to use the "Trie data structure", the thing is that I have to get the words from a file (I know how to do it) but I've implemented this Interface

```
public interface Trie {

public void add();
public boolean query(String word);
public boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Then I have a class `TreeTrie` which has a inner class Node

```
public class TreeTrie implements Trie{

private static int cardinalityAlphabet= 0;
private Node node;
private ArbreTrieTau(int cardinality){
    this.cardinalityAlphabet= cardinality;
}

private class Node{
    Node[] n;
    public Node(int num){
        //+1 because of centinel
        this.n = new Node[num+1];
    }

}
```

Now I'm stuck because I don't know how to start to create the tree, I mean I don't have to build it now, I have to implement the method add, query, isEmpty(), also I think on method add it requires a String word as query method, and then I have to get the `charAt(0)` of that word and create a new Node of it? 
Do I have to create another method that converts the index 0 to "a", index 1 to "b", etc?

The tree es something like this :

[image]

Note* the centinel is the last item of the array not the first.

I can't use list I have to use [].

Comment: Did you consider to use the java TreeNode interface instead of defining your own Structure of Data? It's quite well documented, and you'll easily find tutorials for it.

Comment: I have to create my own. Don't know why downvote my question it's anormal question, I know there are interfaces that does that job but in my case I have to create my own.

Comment: @Stuart2041 What is exactly the main problem that is blocking you? What I see is that basically you need to implement a data structure for optimizing search of words like in a vocabulary. A first problem that I see in your interface is that you should have a `String`parameter in your `add` method. I think this is the method you would use for adding words to your vocabulary. Regarding usage of arrays this makes sense. I think in every node you should have an array of `N` items, where `N` is the number of  letters of your alphabet :)